# How to create my own table based on the count number of numbers from a column?

Tags: postgresql

I have more columnns my table "vb10_cartridgedata" but the following two columns are my columns of interest: "NestID"  and "FailCode": The "NestID"can only deliver numbers from 1-16. So I am trying to count how many times did the FailCode=11 showed up for NestID =1... or how many times did the FailCode=4 showed up for NestID= 4... (for every nest)...

| NestID | FailCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 25 |
| 4 | 32 |
| 4 | 32 |

Conceptually, I am expecting to construct a table which provides me this for every cell:
[note that if for Ch1 and Ch2 Coumnns I get a null, nulls should be represented as 0]

| NestID | Ch1 | Ch2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =1 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =1 |
| 2 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =2 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =2 |
| 3 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =3 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =3 |
| 4 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =4 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =4 |
| 5 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =5 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =5 |
| 6 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =6 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =6 |
| 7 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =7 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =7 |
| 8 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =8 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =8 |
| 9 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =9 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =9 |
| 10 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =10 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=10 |
| 11 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =11 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=11 |
| 12 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =12 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=12 |
| 13 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =13 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=13 |
| 14 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =14 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=14 |
| 15 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =15 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=15 |
| 16 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =16 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=16 |

So, I am expecting to see something like this:

| NestID | Ch1 | Ch 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 33 | 173 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 20 | 28 |
| 5 | 0 | 193 |
| 6 | 1 | 27 |
| 7 | 203 | 1 |
| 8 | 13 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 | 261 |
| 10 | 20 | 0 |
| 11 | 173 | 23 |
| 12 | 0 | 53 |
| 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | 5 | 14 |
| 16 | 106 | 0 |

I've tried the following, but it's not working for me (please see the picture to see what I am getting):

```
SELECT "NestID",
"FailCode",
count ("FailCode"=23) as "CH1", count ("FailCode"=11) as "CH2"
FROM public.vb10_cartridgedata
group by 1, 2;
```

[Picture of my Query Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFOpB.png)

Comment: I removed the tags for the 4 unsupported Postgres versions. If you are really still using an unsupported version, then please add only one tag for that version.

Comment: You are looking for `count(*) filter (where ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The following is what solved my problem. Thanks for the help in this other post from [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319149/how-to-count-rows-matching-certain-conditions-within-each-group/319159#319159) Sorry for cross-posting

```
SELECT distinct ("NestID"),
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =23) as "CH1",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =11) as "CH2"
FROM public.vb10_cartridgedata
group by 1
;
```

[Image of Solved issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXvdJ.png)